# How to get the output classes path of the project in the eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to get the absolute path of the output folder. It may be a link to a folder outside the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the system path of the output of a project programmatically (for an eclipse plugin), you could use [**`IJavaProject`**](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html):

```
IPath path = project.getOutputLocation();
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IFolder folder = root.getFolder(path);
return folder.getLocation();
```

Also [detailed here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg62384.html):

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(javaProject.getOutputLocation()).getLocation();
```

Comment: ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getWorkspaceRoot() should be ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

Comment: @James: very true (as mentioned in `the IWorkspace` API). I have updated the post with this correction.