# Determining if an IFolder is a Java output folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In my Eclipse plugin, I have an `IFolder` in a Java project, and I want to determine if that folder is an output folder for the project.  I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032038/how-to-get-the-output-classes-path-of-the-project-in-the-eclipse-plugin) and am aware of the method [`IJavaProject.getOutputLocation()`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html#getOutputLocation()).  However, that method only returns the *default* output location for the project.  It is possible for the user to reconfigure the build path to use another location as the output folder instead.  Plus, there may be multiple source folders, each with their own configured output location.

Given all of this, how can I effectively determine if the `IFolder` is in fact an output folder?  Is there some API I can use to get a list of all output locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the individual Java Build Path entries yourself and examine whether they are for a source kind and whether those designate an output location: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html#getRawClasspath-- .

Comment: ah yes, I always forget about `IClasspathEntry`.  Thanks.